# exception thrown by query through Mysqldb in python. It is being executed at mySQL directly

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am try to calling a function to execute a query:

```
def run(self,query):       
        try:
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor ()
            self.cursor.execute(query)
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            logger.info( "Run function with query: %s Error %d: %s" % (query,e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        except:
            logger.info( "Errorin Run function with query %s" % (query))
```

This function is working good for mot of the queries.

There is one query which I am trying to run:

```
insert into NewBooks (title,WikiLink) values
   ('Five Point Someone – What not to do at IIT!',
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five Point Someone – What not to do at IIT!')
```

This query throws an exception and output is `Errorin Run function with query %s" % (query)`
Traceback error:
Error: I am getting is UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 120: ordinal not in range(256)

When I copied and ran on Mysql Command line, It worked. Could some one explain me what could be going wrong?

Comment: That'd be a python syntax error, and most likely nothing to do with mysql. If the query was bad somehow, you'd get a mysql error message explaining why it's bad.

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: I am getting Error 1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: Error: I am getting is UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 120: ordinal not in range(256)

Answer (score 0):

You have some special characters in that query, and your default locale is latin-1 (iso-8859-1). When python tries to print out the error message and include your query, it fails to encode your unicode object to bytes (which it has to do, since you can only send bytes over a pipe, not code points).

You might try running using a utf-8 capable terminal, making sure your locale is utf-8 friendly, or explicitly specifying how you want to encode the query data for output.

One good quick change would be to use `%r` on that line instead of `%s`.

```
logger.info( "Errorin Run function with query %r" % (query,))
```

This would just show the query object in a way that you could paste it back into Python, so special characters would be escaped.

Also, you're swallowing the actual error that should be showing, by catching everything with a bare "except". You should really either take that out and let Python show you the traceback itself, or put

```
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

under that last bare `except:`.

Comment: How can I make string utf-8 / there could be many symbols in a huge data set

Comment: How do you mean %r didn't work? What did it do instead of work?

Comment: In general, you encode a unicode object to a particular encoding (including utf-8) with the `.encode()` method, like `query.encode('utf-8')`. But that may not help much for printing to stdout if your locale and terminal don't understand utf-8. And there may be other encoding issues at play between mysql and your input.

Comment: %r added 'u' to my query and then if I execute that sql gave an error

Comment: Ok, but now you should no longer be getting the encoding error from Python; that was the point of the %r. To be able to see the error that's coming back from your mysql library, add the `traceback.print_exc()` call as I mentioned.